# how to copy a object with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deep-copy

I would like to use deep_dup to duplicate the parent and child objects and save as a new record using rails 5. I have been searching to see some example code to implement it on my project but so far i could not find anything.

so far i did this but it does not work.

```
def copy

  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @newproduct = @product.clone :include => :productlines
  success = @newproduct.save

  if success && @newproduct.errors.empty?
    redirect_to (edit_product_path(@newproduct))
    flash[:danger] = "Procut copied"
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Procut  cannot be copied"
  end

end
```

```
<%= link_to "Clone", copy_product_path(@product), :method => :put %>
```

the gem deep_cloneable is available but i could not understand the documantation, no idea how to use it.

Can anyone just show me a way to implement this on my project?

Would be really appreciated if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to use the [deep_clone](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable#association-inclusion) method to include the productlines association (Also make sure it's not supposed to be `product_lines`).

```
@new_product = @product.deep_clone include: :productlines
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your answer but i still dont get it. If you know how to use this gem can you please explain? How should be my controller and how should i call it in my view? Do i need to change my routes for the copy path?